# Clang libtooling: how to print compiler macro definitions

Tags: clang, libtooling

I have a LibTooling based utility and I would like to output a list of macro definitions for debug purposes. One can print compiler macro definitions with `clang/gcc -dM -E -`, but it does not seem to work if I pass `-dM -E` or `-dD` to ClangTool. Is it possible to do so with LibTooling API or CLI options in any way? It does not matter if it will include macros defined in a parsed source code or not.

I've looked at other similar questions, and as far as I can tell they all are about macros expanded in a parsed source code. That's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is blindingly obvious—in retrospect. `clang::Preprocessor::getPredefines()` returns just that—a list of compiler predefines. The preprocessor object can be obtained e.g. from `clang::CompilerInstance`, as an argument in `clang::DiagnosticConsumer::BeginSourceFile()`, etc.

Just for the sake of completeness, this functionality is not available via libclang API, but I could do that using the fact that all predefines are present in the beginning of a translation unit. So after parsing I just listed all top-level cursors of `CursorKind.MACRO_DEFINITION` that are not in any real location (`location.file is None` using python bindings notation)